# Jibx - Default namespace issue

Tags: java, jibx

Getting default namespace conflict on mapping reference; on structure element sample2.

```xml
<mapping name="sample" class='com.company.test.AccountType'>
    <namespace uri="http://com/company/test" default="elements"/>
    <namespace uri="http://com/company/test/common" prefix="pre"/>

    <value name="sample1" field="sample1" usage="optional"/>
    
    <structure name="sample2" field="sample 2" usage="optional"        
        type="com.company.test.common.NameAddressType"/>
    
    <structure name="sample3" field="sample3" usage="optional" 
        type='com.company.test.CommitmentType'/>
</mapping>
```

I tried to update some of the projects which are on java 1.6 to 1.8. At that I came to know that we were using jibx 1.1 version so I updated with jibx 1.4 version that time I was getting this default namespace error.